# error when using puppeter to login in page

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I am trying to login to page . but when i trying to run the code in chrome I got error .

But when i trying to login page the page give me an error -
"THE SESSION HAS EXPIRED
The page has been inactive for some time and so your session has been logged off for security reasons. Identify yourself to access your account again."

```
I tried to delete the history but it doesnt work.
```

This is my code :

```
async function login(page) {

try {
    await page.goto(loginPageUrl);

    await page.waitForSelector(MAIL_SELECTOR)
    await page.click(MAIL_SELECTOR, { clickCount: 3 });
    await page.keyboard.type(mail);

    await page.waitForSelector(PASSWORD_SELECTOR, { visible: true });

    await page.click(PASSWORD_SELECTOR, { clickCount: 3 });
    await page.keyboard.type(password);

    await page.click(BUTTON_SELECTOR);

    await page.waitForNavigation()
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

and before I start puppeter -

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      defaultViewport: null,
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hy;q=0.8'
    });
login(page)
```